# Application Layout Material Drawer responsiveness of angular components in AngularDart

Tags: dart, material-design, angular-dart, angular-components, dart-webui

[image]

Applied the application layout of angular components in an angular dart project, but the drawer layout is not responsive. Can anyone help me with this, and also I am not able to fixed the header position in the layout.

Comment: Can you share a simple reproduction of this issue? I can't seem to recreate it without more info.

Comment: I have resolved the issue by setting up the position in css.